# mysql select record that have two rows

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a student_table as follows:

```
original_student            other_student
10123                       20234    
10234                       20456
```

And I have other table containing student class

```
Student_code                Class
10123                       class_001
20234                       class_002     
10234                       class_003
20456                       class_004
```

My question is for the student_table, how can I find out that the total count of class is greater than or equal to 2 for the row of original_student and other_student, I need to count by combining the original_student and other_student.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.original_student, s.other_student, count(*) 
from student_table s      
inner join student_class c1 on c1.Student_code = s.original_student
inner join student_class c2 on c2.Student_code = s.other_student
group by s.original_student, s.other_student
having count(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Thanks juergen. But I need to count the class for each pair of original_student and other_student. e.g. 10123 20234 is a pair, I need to count the number of class by adding these two students in the same row. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single join using an `IN(...)` join condition:

```
select s.original_student, s.other_student, count(distinct sc.class) 
from student_table s      
join student_class sc on sc.Student_code in (s.original_student, s.other_student)
group by s.original_student, s.other_student
having count(distinct sc.class) > 1
```

The `distinct` is used in the `count()` in case each student is is associated with the same class code, which (probably) shouldn't count as two classes but rather just the one class.